# Error sending parameters to php

Tags: php, android

when  connecting android to php sometimes parameters not sent.

```
user=i.getExtras().getString("user");
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user",user));
// getting JSON string from URL
json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_orders, "GET", params);
```

result obtained based on empty user.

Answer (score 0):

> This worked for me try this :

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://URL.com.php");
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", value1));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", value2));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent())  
            .toString()
```

Comment: Thanks dear, i am using the same code. i have used the androidhive tutorial. and i m using the wamp server. the problem is: when i run the mobile app and display the orders(orders of given user -user is param - ) the orders are displayed correctly. if rerun the same activity it displays sometimes empty list. because the associated php script test the _GET('user') and found it empty. My question is: the problem is from wamp server or from the mobile app? there are some configurations need to be done? plz help,

Comment: i would suggest to see logs :1. data going from android to php script and 2. data revecived to php script ..if u are getting data sometimes then there must be some programticall error in ur code

Comment: // getting JSON string from URL
   json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_orders_details, "GET", params);
   
   

   try {
    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

    if (success == 1) {
     //logcat.setText(json.toString());
     // products found
     // Getting Array of Products
     ordersdetails = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ORDERS_DETAILS);

Comment: // looping through All Products
     for (int i = 0; i < ordersdetails.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject c = ordersdetails.getJSONObject(i);

      // Storing each json item in variable
      String product = c.getString(TAG_PRODUCT);
      String qty = c.getString(TAG_QTY);
 

      // creating new HashMap
      HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

Comment: // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
      map.put(TAG_PRODUCT, product);
      map.put(TAG_QTY, qty);
 
      // adding HashList to ArrayList
      ordersDetailsList.add(map);
     }
    } else {

Comment: jsonParser is the same at http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: hey are u always passing the parameter to php script?

Comment: each time open the activity in onCreate pass the parameter and obtains the result